# svelte component wont access .env

Tags: javascript, fetch, svelte, sveltekit

So ive been able to get this to work before but im getting this error when trying to access an API while hiding the key

i was hoping to run everything in this one svelte component to make life easier

```
<script>
import 'dotenv/config';
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

// Fetch the data when the component is created
async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.sportmonks.com/v3/football/leagues?api_token=${API_KEY}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data.data;
}

let leagues = [];
async function load() {
  leagues = await fetchData();
}

// Initialize the data when the component is created
$: {
  load();
} 
</script> 

{#each leagues as league}
   <div>{league.name}</div>
{/each}
```

here is my error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a hidden key inside a *.svelte file, code running in frontend components is always public.

When you're using SvelteKit you can use [$env/static/private](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private) or [$env/dynamic/private](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private) inside `+page.server.js` & `+server.js` files inside the src/routes/ folder.

These files run on (as the name implies) on the server and have access to private environment variables.

```
import { API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
```

Then make the api call on the server and return the results as data/props.